# MacBook Pro screen resolution confusion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, resolution

I noticed something weird on my Mac:

The resolution in specs is 2560x1600 (13" MBP). In System Preferences, It says that the resolution "looks like 1440x900", but does not mention the actual resolution.

When I take a screenshot, the resolution is 2880x1800 (in the screenshot file's metadata)

The screenshot.app in CMD+Shift+4 mode shows a crossbow with coordinates, the coordinates say 1439, 899 when moved to the bottom-right corner.

And third-party apps (like OBS) show 1440x900 as the resolution.

Why is that happening and what's the "actual" resolution of my screen?

**Edit** output of `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` as requested by @ankii:

```
Graphics/Displays:

    Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650:

      Chipset Model: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650
      Type: GPU
      Bus: Built-In
      VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
      Vendor: Intel
      Device ID: 0x5927
      Revision ID: 0x0006
      Metal: Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily2 v1
      Displays:
        Color LCD:
          Display Type: Built-In Retina LCD
          Resolution: 2560 x 1600 Retina
          Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
          Main Display: Yes
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
          Connection Type: Internal
```

Comment: Please add the output of `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` command

Comment: @ankii I have added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many many OS X versions ago, Apple rolled out "Resolution Independent UI" in order to ensure that UI elements were rendered consistently regardless of the DPI of the display. Prior to this, all displays were assumed to operate at 72 pixels per inch (ppi). Prior to that, if you wanted the main Mac menu bar to be 3/8" high, you would simply multiply 3/8 by 72 to set how tall the element is.

Why do I bring this up? Because with this foundation in place, Apple rolled out retina displays with DPIs approaching 300 ppi. Your display is one of these and indeed has a *Fixed* dpi of `2560x1600` (per specs). The underlying resolution independence ensures that the UI elements display at a consistent size across resolutions, screen sizes, and pixel densities.

In summary, from my understanding:

- Your Screen's resolution is fixed at `2560x1600px` (see note below)
- Your "virtual" resolution is set in displays preferences, and you have it set to "look like" `1440x900`
- "Full Screen" screenshots `(⌘-⇪-3)` appear to capture in "native" display resolution. (see note below)
- "Marquee" screenshots `(⌘-⇪-4)` appear to capture in "virtual" display resolution.

**note**: The `2880x1800` resolution in your screenshot appears to be a `2x` of your virtual resolution of `1440x900`

Answer (score 0):

To see the physical pixel count of your monitor, choose *Apple menu > About this Mac > Displays* (tab).

Here is an example of my external BenQ 4K monitor along with built-in screen for MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020). The [official specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP824?locale=en_US) confirm:

> 13.3-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with IPS technology; 2560-by-1600 native resolution at 227 pixels per inch with support for millions of colors

[image: screenshot of Apple menu > About this Mac > Displays (tab)]

I too have found it frustrating that the *System Report* button does *not* report the actual system.

Here is a screen shot of those same two monitors, with no mention of real pixel count.

[image]